# Probability Question about Cholesterol

Tags: probability

Cholesterol values which exceed 240 in an adult are classified as high.  If a given age group of adults has cholesterol values which are normally distributed with a mean of 180 and a standard deviation of 25, the percent classified as high in this group is what number?

Comment: How far is 240 from 180?  What would that look like as a z-score?  What is a z-score?  Where do you find the probability once you have your score?

Answer (score 2):

You know that the variable is distributed Normally with parameters $\mu=180$ and $\sigma=25$, but as you should know in order to solve the problem you have to standardise the distribution of your variable:

$$z=\frac{X-\mu}\sigma$$

Once you calculate the value of $z$ you go to the Standard Normal table and you search your value. Generally the table shows you the area to the left of the Z-score. So the number you are searching for will be 1 minus the value you obtained **from the table**